# Script to find pdf files based on IDs

Tags: awk, grep

I have 500 IDs for students in an excel file (I have only one column for IDs) and I need to find the reports (pdf files) for each student among the 2K pdf files. These files are in one folder.
Finally, I want to move extracted files into a new folder

So how can I find the pdf file containing the specific ID and move it to a new folder?

I hope my question is clear

Thanks in advance

Comment: You could save the Excel file as a CSV, call some Unix text processing tool (e.g. `awk` possibly) to print the IDs from the CSV, then call `find` to find the PDF files named based on those IDs.

Comment: Are the IDs in the files or in the file names?

Comment: Please add sample input (no descriptions, no images, no links) and your desired output for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Why should a .pdf contain a student ID? PDFs have a complex structure. In general, admin data is plain text on short lines like `DateCreated: 2023-01-17 16:42:17`, but content is held in anonymous compressed blocks. I also see at least 4 versions of format, even from the same organisation. Recognising a specific student ID depends crucially on how it is embedded.

Comment: @Paul_Pedant I assumed the OP meant the name of the file contained the ID rather than the contents of the file, hopefully the OP will clarify.

Comment: @EdMorton  Agreed it is ambiguous -- I chose the more difficult case. Also, OP needs to clarify "move extracted files into a new folder" -- I suspect this means "create a new directory for each unique student ID, and move all their files into there". I also do not see any purpose for the Excel file -- the IDs (whether in the filename or the contents) provide their own grouping. Maybe the dir-names have to be the student name from the Excel (in which case, beware duplicate student names -- unique IDs are there for a purpose).